# How to create all folders in a path in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Basically I need to create all folders in this path "C:\Users\Desktop\Info\Clients\Data"
But not even the base "Info" directory exists, and there are many other paths I need to create, What's the best way I can go about doing this?

Comment: Creating an 'existing' folder is cheap - it will fail, but you can ignore the failure. Just always create all of them.

Comment: @Jongware I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Have you at least tried this?  .NET is smart enough to create any missing intermediary folders.  Use My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory().  And don't hard-code c:\users, use Environment.GetFolderPath() so you can't forget the user name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class Directory in the namespace System.IO has a method called [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) that, as from MSDN remarks, creates every directory mentioned in the path passed.

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
>   already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. If the directory
>   already exists, this method does not create a new directory, but it
>   returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory.

So you just need

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Desktop\Info\Clients\Data")
```

and all the directories will be created if they don't exist.

In this specific example, as explained in a comment above from Hans Passant, you should try to avoid to use an hard coded path. The enumeration [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) is a symbolic reference to numerous well known location on your hard disk. You could pass an element of this enumeration to [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) to get back a physical path on your hard disk

```
Dim userDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
Dim fullPath = Path.Combine(userDesktop, "INFO\Clients\Data")
Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath)
```

Comment: Great answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried created some new folders using

Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Desktop\Info\Clients\Data")

but the directories created are not visible on the screen. However I did a search using the search facility in the file explorer tab and it can locate them, so they must exist. I also did a restart in case this made them appear, but no it did not.